# pd.eval with dynamic column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, eval

I’m generating new columns in a dataframe in a loop where the column names are dynamically set in each loop, and would like to use DataFrame.eval() if possible.  E.g.,

```
for i in roll_windows_values:
    readFromColName = 'Movement _' + str(i)
    newColName = readFromColName + '_deviation'
    df[newColName] = df.eval('readFromColName.mean() - readFromColName')
```

This gives me the error

```
pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'readFromColName' is not defined
```

I’ve also tried treating the column name as a variable:

```
df[newColName] = df.eval('@readFromColName.mean() - @readFromColName')
```

But this gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Load' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Would anyone know how I can column names from string variables in Dataframe.eval?

Comment: You do not need eval `df[readFromColName].mean()-df[readFromColName]`

Comment: @YOBEN_S - As in `eval` won't affect process speed?

Comment: No, what @YOBEN_S is trying to say is that your problem is simple enough that it does not require `pd.eval`. Perhaps this is a boiled down version of what you're trying to do and for some reason you're not actually allowed to directly create expressions as YOBEN_S has showed in their previous comment?

Comment: many thanks @cs95 - yes I should have been clearer - `df[readFromColName].mean()-df[readFromColName]` works fine, but I was looking for a way to speed up the calculations. pd.eval looked promising and worked well for non-dynamic column names, but couldn't get it running when the column names where read from string.

Comment: OK great, [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62687071/4909087) should work. Although be warned pd.eval may or may not actually speed your code up. Best thing to do is test/benchmark your code.

Comment: I will time it before/after cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you need `eval` to work with dynamic column names, you can do this with `pd.eval` accordingly:

```
df[newColName] = pd.eval('df[readFromColName].mean() - df[readFromColName]')
```

Note that top level `eval` calls don't require the `@variable` annotation.

Comment: I do get the following error when trying this: `ValueError: unknown type str1440` - with the last digits seeming to depend on the length of `readFromColName`. I'm running pandas 0.25.3 - would that have something to do with it?

Comment: @snilsson Not sure, try upgrading to 1.0 though, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use an f-string?

```
df.eval(f'{readFromColName}.mean() - {readFromColName}')
```